# Graphical illustration for quintic impossibility problem

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I am looking for simplified method that explains the impossibility of solving quintic equation in radicals so that the students who are not familiar with Galois group can understand the quintic impossibility problem in an easy-understood way.

In the following image there are some points that needs to be connected to each other without line intersection in 2D plane.

As shown, we can easily connect all the points one-to-one up to the 4-points shape, but it is impossible to connect all points together in 5-points shape and higher whatever the points are arranged.

*(in 5-points shape, you can draw up to 9 lines but the last one cannot be drawn without lines intersection)*

Now the method is clear and simple , but we need to make a relation between these points connection and the roots of related $nth$ polynomial equation.

**So, is it possible to explain it this way, Or there is no relation between these shapes and polynomial roots?**

and that is what I am searching for, but still have no clear result.
[image]

Comment: I don't see any direct relation between these two things. Note that some quintics do have roots that can be written with radicals. It's just not true in general.

Comment: The solvability of a polynomial using  radicals only depends on the fact that the Galois group is sovable or not. This possibility first occurs for the fifth degree because the symmetric group of order  $5!$ is the smallest symmetric group that is not solvable. Moreover for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are polynomials of degree $n$ that are solvable, e.g. the cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I know , but solvable quintics or rational quintics can also be described by rational lines , and one should searches for a relation belongs to this instead of refusing the idea by just looking at it.